# think something of something/somebody

Tags: vocabulary

When I came across this sentence, *“What did you think of Bombyx Mori?”*, in *[the Silkworm](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2014/jun/18/the-silkworm-review-jk-rowling-robert-galbraith)*, I re-read CGEL’s page 909, which was led by [@snailboat’s comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34857/how-did-you-like-the-concert#comment66138_34857). Then, I thought out this construction: *I think <something> of Bombyx Mori*. But I can’t find out any of this structure in dictionaries. Isn’t this structure used in declaratives?

Comment: Do you expect another word (or phrase) to be used instead of "something"?  Or do you expect "I think something of Bombyx Mori" to be said without any substitutions?

Comment: @Jasper, I'd like to know both of them. (I don't suppose one excludes the other - am I wrong?)

Comment: Probably except for "I think the best/worst/world of someone", the common expression would be "I think of [someone] as [something]."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some possible substitutions.  They sound old-fashioned to my (American) ear:

> When I think of silkworms, I think only of *Bombyx Mori*.
>
> I think well of *Bombyx Mori*.
>
> I think ill of *Bombyx Mori*.
>
> I think not of *Bombyx Mori*.
>
> I think of *Bombyx Mori* every day.
>
> I think highly of *Bombyx Mori*.
>
> I think the world of *Bombyx Mori*.  ("I think the world of..." is a superlative form of "I think well of..." or "I think highly of...".)
>
> My mother told me to be nice, or keep my peace.  So I say nothing of *Bombyx Mori*.  ("about" sounds more natural to me than "of".)
>
> Sometimes we take miracles for granted.  I think nothing of *Bombyx Mori*.
>
> Yes, I think something of *Bombyx Mori*!  Do you want to know what I think of *Bombyx Mori*?

Most of these substitutions are adverbs, which modify "think".