# How do you like this hat?

Tags: vocabulary

> **How** do you like this hat? ([RHD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_House_Webster's_Unabridged_Dictionary))

The example’s ‘*how*’ is included in the denotation of ‘*to what extent or degree*’ ([here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/how?s=t), adverb how#2 in its online version). But when I look up [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/how-do-you-like), it seems to be ‘used when asking someone for an opinion.’ [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/like_2) also seems to have the opinion as in: How did you like Japan (= did you find it pleasant)? In OALD, ‘*like*’ having this meaning, *to find something pleasant*, ‘*how*’ seems to be that it’s a kind of dummy - pleonastic? I don't find proper words - word: I mean, without ‘how’ it can make sense.
It’s very difficult to understand the ‘*how*,’ so I asked the Korean interpretation to a Korean language institute - I asked about this sentence: “How do you like this dress?” (Of course, it was Korean sentence - [어떻게 이 옷 마음에 들어](https://twitter.com/EyeJoo/status/451850386727370753)?” not English -- it's not a place for asking foreign languages, only for my own tongue, so it would not be directly applied -- I tried this to understand the *how* indirectly from my language for I don’t understand the *how* in English way.). They say the Korean ‘*how*’ (어떻게) in the case is a kind of interjection, used colloquially. When I interpret the example from RHD, based on the institute’s Korean word explanation, I guess it would be making sense in English, too. I’m afraid if I could deliver what I think well, but what do you think of the ‘*how*’?

Comment: In your example *"How do you like this hat?"*, you could say that ***how*** doesn't really "mean" anything at all. In almost all contexts it would make little or no difference whether it was present or not. You could understand it as meaning *"To what extent (if at all) do you like this?"* if that helps you. But note that this usage is somewhat different to *"How do you **clean** this hat?"* *(**what method** do you use to clean it?)*.

Comment: ...having said all that, I don't actually understand the *question* here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Yes, it's always hard to deliver the concept that I don't know well to others, and for readers it would be excruciatingly difficult to catch the gist, I guess. But your comment is very helpful, for I've not yet found the kind in any dictionaries, except that yours is somewhat similar - to me - with the aforementioned Korean answerer. I'm very much obliged for this comment.

Comment: I'm sure you know by now that most of the problems you face learning English aren't really to do with *vocabulary* as such. Thousands of ordinary nouns and verbs are really easy to use so long as you've seen and can remember a simple *definition* (often, a single English word has a single close equivalent in Korean or whatever). The real problems involve a few dozen (at most a few hundred) short general-purpose words (prepositions, conjunctions, pronouns, etc.). Because they often have a number of non-intuitive aspects about exactly how they're used (which may not be consistently observed! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree that "how" has no meaning in that sentence. "Did you like that hat?" invites a yes/no answer; "How did you like that hat?" means "To what extent did you like that hat?" and invites a much more nuanced answer.

Comment: There's also a bit about this "how" usage in the 2002 *CGEL*, page 908, "(b) Adverbial degree modifier". Example [16.iv] *"How did you like the concert?"* That seems to have the meaning of "How much did you like the concert?", and so, your example seems to have the meaning of "How much do you like this hat?"

Comment: @F.E. Thank you so much. I've once read the same page, which was lead by [@snailboat](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34857/how-did-you-like-the-concert), but I've forgot that. After reading your comment, I asked again to them about _Korean how_ - this time ['얼마나'](https://twitter.com/EyeJoo/status/525418026980499456), which is adverbial degree modifier. It's a way of possible expression. So the lack of my imagination prevented the understaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*How* has several meanings, among them "in what manner" and "to what degree|extent".

The precise definition of one sense of *how* ("to what extent or degree") and a definition that describes the social context of its use ("used when asking someone for an opinion") are not really at odds with each other. The opinion sought in that social context is "to what extent or degree" the person asked regards a thing to possess a certain quality.

**How do you like this dress?**

[Do you think it looks|will look good, or very good, on me? Or not good at all?]

**Tell me, how do you like your new school?**

[To what extent has it met your hopes and expectations?]

Answer (score -2):

'How' in this context is a slang-style usage originating in America, and essentially a contracted version of 'How much do you like this hat?'

I've never heard or seen it used in the UK in normal conversation, and a more typical usage would be 'Do you like this hat?' Or more informally 'How great/good is this hat?'

Comment: It did not originate in America: *How do you like* (or *How like you* in EME) has been current in English at least since *Common Conditions*, ca 1576.

Comment: "Do you like this hat?" invites a yes/no answer; "How do you like this hat?" (which seems perfectly natural to me as a native British speaker) invites a more detailed answer and means something like "To what degree and in what ways do you like this hat?"